# less -j is not working for me

Tags: less

`less -jn` where n is a line number to jump to is not working for me. It just has no effect. I'm running less version 436 on Ubuntu 11.04. I also tried `less --jump-target=200` and `LESS='-j200' less filename`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`-j` configures how search works (it's where on the screen to position the line containing the search result). I think you're looking for

```
less +200 filename           # jump to line 200 (the first line is 1)
```

The `+NUM` switch to jump to line NUM is fairly common amongst unix text viewers (starting with `more`) and editors. In less, it's an instance of the more general `+command` which lets you execute a command automatically after opening the file. Other common examples:

```
less +200P filename          # jump to the line containing byte 200
less +G filename             # jump to the end of the file (G command)
less +/hello filename        # jump to the first occurrence of hello
```

Comment: The link to "ceving's answer" no longer works. Any chance the answer could be updated to synthetically explain what `-j` does? (e.g. "`-j` only sets the starting line for searches and other jumps")

Comment: @ricab ok, done.